# Components rules from ArrayComponents

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, gathering

What is the most efficient way to get component rules from ArrayComponents, so additionaly to

```
data = {"a", "b", "a"};
cmp = ArrayComponents[data]
```

> ```
>  {1,2,1}
> ```

I would like to get:

```
Thread[data -> cmp] // DeleteDuplicates
```

> ```
> {"a"->1, "b"->2}
> ```

(*or reversed*), and the point is that the data is big and I don't want to compare it again to get those relations.

Failed to find the solution in documentation or here.

Comment: But you can run it once to generate the `ArrayComponents`?, so use `temp = Flatten@
   Trace[ArrayComponents[{"a", "b", "d", "c", "a"}], Replace];` and then `Extract[]`?

Comment: Slower than goldberg's answer, already ran comparison.

Comment: Is the reason that `"a"` gets `1` and `"b"` gets `2` that `"a"` occurs first in your list, or that `"a"` occurs before `"b"` in the alphabetical order?

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom occurence matters I suppose.

Answer (score 8):

What about this:

```
data = {"a", "b", "a"};
AssociationThread[data, ArrayComponents[data]] // Normal
```

> `{"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2}`

I suggest this because building an association automatically removes duplicates. It should be fairly fast because it is hashing.

Answer (score 7):

Here are three functions that do the job relatively fast.

```
<< Developer`
ranFirstPos =
 Compile[
  {{ints, _Integer, 1}, {max, _Integer}},
  Block[
   {res, ii}
   ,
   ii = 1;
   Table[
    While[
     ints[[ii]] != jj
     ,
     ii++
     ];
    ii
    ,
    {jj, 1, max}
    ]
   ]
  ]

jacobFu[data_] :=
 Module[
  {cmp, max, dataDD},
  cmp = ToPackedArray@ArrayComponents@data;
  max = Max@cmp;
  dataDD = data[[ranFirstPos[cmp, max]]];
  Thread[Rule[dataDD, Range[max]]]
  ]
```

Or

```
kubaImprovedFu[data_] :=
 Module[
  {cmp}
  ,
  cmp = ArrayComponents[data];
  Thread[DeleteDuplicates /@ Rule[data, cmp]]
  ]
```

The following alternative does not really answer the question of "how to deal with the result of `ArrayComponents`", as it doesn't use `ArrayComponents`. This one can be made slightly faster by using `` System`Utilities`HashTable `` rather than an `Association`.

```
jacobFuAssocHash[data_] :=
 Module[{jj, assoc},
   assoc = Association[];
   jj = 1;
   Reap[
    Do[
     If[
      ! KeyExistsQ[assoc, elem],
      assoc[elem] = True;
      Sow[elem -> jj];
      jj++
      ]
     ,
     {elem, data}
     ]
    ]
   ][[2, 1]]
```

**Timing comparison**

From other posts, we define

```
kubaFu[data_] :=
 Module[
  {cmp}
  ,
  cmp = ArrayComponents[data];
  Thread[data -> cmp] // DeleteDuplicates
  ]

goldbergFu[data_] :=
 AssociationThread[data, ArrayComponents[data]] // Normal
```

This gives us

```
nn = 10^7;
data = FromCharacterCode /@ RandomInteger[{0, 65536 - 1}, nn];
jacobRes = jacobFu[data];//Timing//First
jacobAsHaRes = jacobFuAssocHash[data]; // Timing // First
kubaImRes = kubaImprovedFu[data];//Timing//First
goldbergRes = goldbergFu[data]; // Timing // First
kubaRes = kubaFu[data]; // Timing // First
jacobRes === jacobAsHaRes === kubaImRes === kubaRes === goldbergRes
```

> ```
> 7.20605
> 9.41933
> 10.207
> 12.3219
> 21.7913
> True
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by @Feyre's comment, we can modify the behavior of [`Dispatch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dispatch) before running [`ArrayComponents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayComponents) to capture the rules:

```
componentRules[list_] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{Dispatch, flag=True},
    Unprotect[Dispatch];
    a_Dispatch /; flag := Block[{flag=False}, Throw[Normal[a][[4;;]]]];
    Catch @ ArrayComponents[list]
]
```

A brief speed comparison:

```
nn = 10^7;
data = FromCharacterCode /@ RandomInteger[{0,65536-1}, nn];
r1 = jacobFu[data]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = componentRules[data]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {7.67635, Null}
>
> {3.21433, Null}
>
> True

Note that this answer and @MrWizard's answer are the only ones that work for matrices or arrays with rank greater than 1.

Comment: In v10.1 I seem to need an `Unprotect[Dispatch];` in there to get things working.  Thanks for demonstrating such an interesting approach!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that ArrayComponents itself can be a bit slow.  Seeking an alternative I tried this:

```
data = FromCharacterCode @ RandomInteger[{97, 122}, {500000, 4}];

r1 = componentRules[data]; // RepeatedTiming   (* Carl Woll's function *)

r2 = 
   Thread[# -> Range@Length@#] &@DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@data]; // RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2
```

> ```
> {0.84, Null}
>
> {0.260, Null}
>
> True
> ```

Comment: This gives an incorrect answer. For instance, `result` is `{"a"->1, "a"->2}` for the list `{"a", "a", "b"}`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks! I thought I was missing something but I couldn't see it.  Embarrassing. <:-o

Comment: Much better. Note that `ArrayComponents` is written in top-level, so I'm not surprised that you can do better.

Answer (score 1):

`SparseArray`, like `Assocoation`, takes the first of repeated entries:

```
data = {"a", "b", "a"};
cmp = ArrayComponents[data];
Most@ArrayRules@SparseArray[cmp -> data]
```

> {{1} -> "a", {2} -> "b"}

To get rid of braces

```
MapAt[## & @@ # &, %, {{All, 1}}]
```

> {1 -> "a", 2 -> "b"}

Also:

```
sa = SparseArray[cmp -> data];
Thread[Flatten@sa["NonzeroPositions"] ->  sa["NonzeroValues"]]
```

> {1 -> "a", 2 -> "b"}

Comment: Not particularly fast, at least in 10.1, but an interesting approach.  The `Thread` method just added is faster.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, haven't checked timings. (I suspect `ArrayRules` is the culprit).